# turn a Result object into a number

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, arcpy

```
**import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *
import math
  # Check out any necessary licenses
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("spatial")
   # OverwriteOutput
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
   # Set Geoprocessing environments
arcpy.env.autoCommit = "1000"
arcpy.env.scratchWorkspace = "D:\\NEO\\GISMODELLING\\BestLocationsModel.mdb"
# arcpy.env.extent = "214386.1775 3837166.9542 256099.9616 3907138.0305"
arcpy.env.extent = "D:\\NEO\\GISMODELLING\\BestLocationsModel.mdb\WasteWaterPlant\\Tart_UTM"
arcpy.env.cellSize = "10"
arcpy.env.mask = "D:\\NEO\\GISMODELLING\\BestLocationsModel.mdb\\WasteWaterPlant\\Tart_UTM"
arcpy.env.workspace = "D:\\NEO\\GISMODELLING\\BestLocationsModel.mdb\\WasteWaterPlant"
EucDist_Aggl = "D:/NEO/GISMODELLING/BestLocationsModel.mdb/EucDist_Aggl"
# Process: Get Raster Properties
Max_Aggl = arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(EucDist_Aggl, "MAXIMUM", "")
print Max_Aggl
delta = int (Max_Aggl)
print delta
a = delta/1000
print a**
```

when I running this code I have this errore

> 44250.27734375
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "D:\NEO\test.py", line 28,
>   in 
>       delta = int (Max_Aggl) TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Result'

I need to use the value of Max_Aggl in loops

I try to learn Python as I go

Answer (score 8):

As from the [ArcGIS help](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002z0000000n000000#ESRI_SECTION1_4BF92292703248F09479E3D45CB23904), getRasterProperties() ...

> ... returns the output values of a tool when it is
>   executed as a Result object. The advantage of a result object is that
>   you can maintain information about the execution of tools, including
>   messages, parameters, and output. These results can be maintained even
>   after several other tools have been run.

you need to get the value of the result using .getOutput(index), which will return your value of interest as an unicode string at index 0. This string can in turn be converted into a numeric variable using float() and int().

```
print int(float(Max_aggl.getOutput(0)))
```

Comment: Thank it's work ,but i have another errore
this is the new part of the last code :

# Process: Get Raster Properties
Max_Aggl = arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(EucDist_Aggl, "MAXIMUM", "")
print (Max_Aggl)
print float(Max_Aggl.getOutput(0))
b = float(Max_Aggl.getOutput(0))
c = b/2
print c
delta = int(Max_Aggl.getOutput(0))
print delta
a = delta/1000
print a

the errore is :

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\NEO\bbbb.py", line 25, in <module>
    delta = int(Max_Aggl.getOutput(0))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '44250.27734375'

Comment: and i need all var : delta ,a ,b,c and int()

thanks

Comment: As looking for result object related posts, I came across this. To just completely close this post, you need to cast your string to float first then to int, such as **int(float(Max_Aggl.getOutput(0)))**.

Comment: @fatih_dur thanks, if the raster is not of integer type, you indeed need float() first. Your suggestion is thus more generic therefore I updated my answer.

Comment: thanks @radouxju, in fact the last issue was not about GIS and it would be fair to leave OP to investigate more, but could not help myself, as I said.